# How to perform search on array if it has items matching then copy those items in another array in ipad app

Tags: ios, arrays, search, copy

I have a app in which i want searching. I have a array resultArray which contain all the things which display like

```
 Book*bookObj=[resultArray objectAtIndex.indexPath.row];
 NSString*test=bookObj.title;
```

I want to perform search on title item in resultArray if search text enter in textfield matches with title with any of the arrays then copy those all array values in testArray.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this as :

```
   NSMutableArray *searchDataMA = [NSMutableArray new];

       for (int i = 0; i < resultArray.count; i++) {

         Book *bookObj=[resultArray objectAtIndex:i];
         NSString*test=bookObj.title;
        NSRange rangeValue1 = [test rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

        if (rangeValue1.length != 0) {

            if (![resultArray containsObject:test]) {
                [searchDataMA addObject:test];
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks it works but can i coppy these searchDataMA into other NSMutableArray

Comment: Yes you can. Copy one array into anothera s : `    NSMutableArray *tempMA = [searchDataMA mutableCopy];
`

Comment: i am accetping answer but the way you have told to copy it copies item but crashed becuase these all items are to be copied like a object.

Comment: It shouldn't. Where are you copying ?

Comment: i am copying after the loop

Comment: Are you getting searchDataMA properly. Have you logged newArray in which you are copying searchDataMA ?

Comment: yes your array is searchDataMA is not storing as a object ProductivoApp[7135:11f03] array: (
    "first photo"
)
2013-08-19 14:34:54.387 ProductivoApp[7135:11f03] array two one is (
    "<ObjectData: 0xb5b8ff0>",
    "<ObjectData: 0xb5b9040>",
    "<ObjectData: 0xb5b9090>",
    "<ObjectData: 0xb5b90e0>",
    "<ObjectData: 0xb5b9130>",
    "<ObjectData:

Comment: array: ( 
    "first photo"
)
this is your array SearchDM and other is the original array from which it search i want SearchDM should also show NSLog log like this as a object

Answer (score 0):

[- (NSArray *)filteredArrayUsingPredicate:(NSPredicate *)predicate](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/filteredArrayUsingPredicate%3a) is exactly the function that you want.  It will return a new array with only the elements that pass the test in the `NSPredicate` object.

For example:

```
NSArray *newArray = [oldArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(Book *evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {
    //Do whatever logic you want to in here
    return [evaluatedObject.title isEqualToString:theTitle];
}];
```

Comment: how will it work it does not work with me gives error that you can not pass subString to String can you write some code please

Comment: Alright, I added a simple example that will check if the titles are equal

Comment: it mean it will check if title is same then run but i want like search if title is Ali and i just write A then it should also work

Comment: Then use a different predicate like the one in the other answer (`if ([strName rangeOfString:searchText].location !=NSNotFound)`).  Don't make everyone spoonfeed you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to take another array for this. this will add your object

```
for (Book * bookObj in resultArray) {
         NSString *strName=[[bookObj.title]lowercaseString];
         if ([strName rangeOfString:searchText].location !=NSNotFound) {
                [arrTemp addObject:bookObj];
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It works for me try this:

```
NSArray *fruits = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Apple", @"Crabapple", @"Watermelon", @"Lemon", @"Raspberry", @"Rockmelon", @"Orange", @"Lime", @"Grape", @"Kiwifruit", @"Bitter Orange", @"Manderin", nil];
NSPredicate *findMelons = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[cd] 'melon'"];
NSArray *melons = [fruits filteredArrayUsingPredicate:findMelons];
NSPredicate *findApple = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF beginswith 'Apple'"];
NSArray *apples = [fruits filteredArrayUsingPredicate:findApple];
NSPredicate *findRNotMelons = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF beginswith 'R' AND NOT SELF contains[cd] 'melon'"];
NSArray *rNotMelons = [fruits filteredArrayUsingPredicate:findRNotMelons];

NSLog(@"Fruits: %@", fruits);
NSLog(@"Melons: %@", melons);
NSLog(@"Apples: %@", apples);
NSLog(@"RNotMelons: %@", rNotMelons);
```

Predicates also have more condition functions, some of which I have only touched on here:

```
beginswith : matches anything that begins with the supplied condition
contains : matches anything that contains the supplied condition
endswith : the opposite of begins with
like : the wildcard condition, similar to its SQL counterpart. Matches anything that fits the wildcard condition
matches : a regular expression matching condition. Beware: quite intense to run
```

The syntax also contains the following other function, predicates and operations:

```
AND (&&), OR (||), NOT (!)
ANY, ALL, NONE, IN
FALSE, TRUE, NULL, SELF
```

Still if don't understand take a look at this link;

[Useful link](http://alexeckermann.com/blog/legacy/filtering-nsarray-with-nspredicates)

Comment: NSPredicate*findApple=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELF beginswith %@",searchTextField.text]];
    
    
    
    appDelegate.detailArray = [appDelegate.detailArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:findApple];